# how to iterate a multiple element in arraylist using interator?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, iterator

**when I try to iterate the multiple values in ArrayList I couldn't do what I can do please help me

here is the customer class**

```
public class customer {
   private String CustomerName;
   private String phoneNumber;
   private String customerId;

    public customer(String customerName, String phoneNumber, String customerId) {
        this.CustomerName = customerName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return CustomerName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public customer addCustomer(String customerName,String customerId,String phoneNumber)
    {
        return new customer(customerName, phoneNumber, customerId);
    }
}
```

*here is my main method*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
           static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           static ArrayList<customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
           static customer customer = new 
         customer("dinesh","9600064079","rd_3033");
           static Iterator<customer> iterate = customers.iterator();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(customer.getCustomerId());
        addCustomer();
        printCustomer();
    }

    public static void addCustomer(){
        System.out.println("enter the customer name : ");
        String customerName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter the customer ID : ");
        String customerId = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter the customerNumber : ");
        String customerNumber = scan.nextLine();
        customer addCustomer = 
        customer.addCustomer(customerName,customerId,customerNumber);
        customers.add(addCustomer);
    }
    public static void printCustomer()
    {
//
        while(iterate.hasNext()){
            customer element = iterate.next();

            System.out.println(customers.indexOf(element));
        }
    }
}
```

**how to iterate a multiple-element while it is in the ArrayList, what can I do?**

*i can do it with a single element while in the arraylist but how to iterate multiple value in arraylist*

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: i try to interate the element stored in customer(arraylist) if it a single value we can iterate it easily but add three element like customernam,id,number that's why i get stucked

Comment: my question is simple that how to iterate a arraylist if it have more than one value at every index like      if the arraylist have color name at index no:1 is red what if it have another value on the same line like index:1->red,blue

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an element to the list after getting the iterator. That iterator is no longer available. Using that iterator will result in the exception `ConcurrentModificationException`. You have to get the iterator after adding all the elements.  You should change `printCustomer()` like this.

```
public static void printCustomer() {
    Iterator<customer> iterate = customers.iterator();
    while (iterate.hasNext()) {
        customer element = iterate.next();
        System.out.println(customers.indexOf(element));
    }
}
```